# loading 20 procedures on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have SQL Server 2008 Express and I need to load 20 procedures. I have them in text file if I simply copy them and try  to run in SQL Server Management Studio it throws me error that it cannot read them, when I insert them one by one it load perfectly. So I was wondering if there is way to load all of them in one statement some thing like pack? I know in Oracle it is possible to use package how about SQL Server?

Comment: You need to post the exact error. 'cannot read them' is not an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put

```
GO
```

at the end of each stored procedure like...

```
create stored procedure test1
AS
BEGIN
END
GO
create stored procedure test2
AS 
BEGIN
END
GO
```

To clarify this is syntax specific to SSMS.

Comment: No ; at the end of prosedure?

Comment: You should not need a ';' at the end.

Comment: The ; is a command terminator.  It isn't generally required (CTEs are an exception for example) but can be a good idea.  GO is a batch separator and is in fact configurable although I don't recommend it.  Using a GO statement is similar to highlighting a segment of code and executing just that segment.

Comment: It's SSMS specific not SQL specific, if I wanted i could change ssms to term my sp's with ;.  ; isn't used very heavily by MS SQL as Kenneth has noted.  http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/77/posts/11331/go-as-batch-separator-customize-batch-separator-in-ssms-amp-sqlcmd-what-would-you-use-instead-of-go.aspx